# How to enable Spring retry using version Spring Retry of 1.0.3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations, spring-aspects

To enable Spring retry one can either enable retry in Java annotation: @EnableRetry within Configuration or specify retry in an XML configuration file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean class="org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration" />
```

Both specification are based on …annotation.RetryConfiguration that started only from the version 1.1.2.  How to enable retry in  XML configuration in the previous versions? Due to compatibility issues I cannot use version 1.1.2.  The retry configuration is as follows:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="retrySave"
        expression="execution( * sfweb.service.webServiceOrders.WsOrderCreationServiceImpl.saveLedger(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="retrySave" advice-ref="retryAdvice"
        order="-1" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="retryAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Retry 1.0.3 did not have AspectJ based AOP support.  Therefore, aspect-style retries will not work with that version.  Instead, retryable code needs to be wrapped inside an instance of a `RetryCallback`.  The generic approach is as follows:

> **1.** Create a `RetryTemplate`

```
SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);

FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(backOffPeriod);

RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy);
```

> **2.** Wrap the retryable code in a `RetryCallback`

```
class FailureProneOperation implements RetryCallback<Void> {
  public void doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
    ...
  }
}
```

> **3.** Execute the retryable code

```
retryTemplate.execute(new FailureProneOperation())
```

Comment: So, if I have a method saveLedger that is called inside a class method- where it should be fitted?

Comment: `doWithRetry(...) { saveLedger(...); }`.

Comment: How to pass the parameter to saveLedger()

Comment: You could expose properties on the wrapper class `FailureProneOperation` on which you can set all the contextual data.  Your proposal in the answer below will also work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the posted answer we need also a code to pass parameters for retryable operations. This can be done in the FailureProneOperation constructor:

```
public FailureProneOperation(OrderSkuLedger orderSkuLedger) {
    this.orderSkuLedger = orderSkuLedger;
}
```